# How to remove the shadow of the draggable item in Angular

Tags: css, angular, drag-and-drop, ng-bootstrap-modal

How can I eliminate the shadow that appears beneath the backdrop when dragging an item within the Bootstrap modal dialog?

As depicted in the accompanying picture, I am attempting to drag the "**Personal Details**" button..[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the backdrop itself, it can disabled by passing via data attributes or JavaScript. For data attributes, append the option name to data-, as in `data-backdrop=""`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#options